# Terminal keeps buffering pressed keys

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, file-descriptor, vt100

I'm writing a VT100 terminal engine but input handling is somehow tricky.
First I initialize my tty with no echoing.

```cpp
static void init_tty() {
    if (tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &ctty) != 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("can not get tty attribute");

    ctty.c_lflag &= ~(FLAG(ICANON) | FLAG(ECHO) | FLAG(ISIG));

    if (tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &ctty) != 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("can not set tty attribute");
}
```

Next I initialize a non-blocking keyboard file descriptor.

```cpp
static void init_keyboard(const char *device) {
    if ((kfd = open(device, FLAG(O_RDONLY) | FLAG(O_SYNC))) == -1)
        throw std::runtime_error("can not open keyboard fd");

    unsigned flags = fcntl(kfd, F_GETFL, 0);

    flags |= FLAG(O_NONBLOCK);

    if (fcntl(kfd, F_SETFL, flags) == -1)
        throw std::runtime_error("can not set keyboard fd flags");
}
```

So far so good. The main loop is just polling events and will break if pressing ESC.

```cpp
int main() {
    while (true) {
        read(kfd, evt, sizeof(input_event));

        if (evt->type == EV_KEY && evt->value == 1 && evt->code == KEY_ESC)
            break;
    }
}
```

So I type some characters. Meanwhile my terminal is buffering all characters that I am typing in. After the program exits all characters got displayed.

So here my question: How can I disable terminal output stream buffering while my program is running?

Here is a GIF to illustrate the problem.

Steps:

- sudo ./clac
- engine is running but not echoing; typing some characters
- pressing ESC
- typed in characters got displayed; program exit

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `read` instead of `fgetc`? `read` with a nonblocking file descriptor will issue the error `EAGAIN` (either or `EWOULDBLOCK`) if you are reading from a file other than a socket and the read would block. (which given it would be attempting to read `sizeof(input_event)` bytes seems likely). I would have to dig further to determine the exact behavior as you have the terminal and file descriptor set. All can be avoided simply by reading with `fgetc` in non-cannonical mode.

Comment: I can't tell from your question what your desired outcome is: a) discarding typed-in characters, or b) immediately displaying typed-in characters. If b), how does your program attempt to display them?

Comment: fgetc seems to work but i cant handle specials keys like 'ESC' with it, besides there is no way of checking if a certain character is pressed or not.

@Armali its a) discarding typed-in characters. The program should not display typed keys thats why i turned of echoing but in the background the keys get buffered. and when the program exits those characters got printed. like i have to flush some buffers befor exit.

Answer (score 0):

> The program should not display typed keys thats why i turned of echoing but in the background the keys get buffered. and when the program exits those characters got printed. like i have to flush some buffers befor exit.

This can be accomplished by calling

```
    tcflush(STDIN_FILENO, TCIFLUSH);
```

just before exiting; see [tcflush(3) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tcflush).

Answer (score 0):

I've just solve my problem. (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126974/where-do-i-find-ioctl-eviocgrab-documented)

So I am grabbing all events immediately after my program starts including ENTER

Example: sudo ./clac ENTER

The solution was to add 1000 milliseconds delay at the start and then GRAB the fd events with

```cpp
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

if (ioctl(kfd, EVIOCGRAB, FD_GRAB) == -1)
    throw std::runtime_error("can not set keyboard fd grab");
```

And when the program exits UNGRAB the fd with

```cpp
if (ioctl(kfd, EVIOCGRAB, FD_UNGRAB) == -1)
    throw std::runtime_error("can not set keyboard fd ungrab");
```